# Pin/Run Akka Actor to Main Thread

Tags: multithreading, scala, opengl, akka

I'm currently poking at using Scala and Akka in an application that uses LWJGL. As is commonly known, you can't really issue OpenGL calls outside of the main thread of the application. This poses a problem if I want to use any actor for rendering (either a single, main actor that, for example, drains a rendering command queue, or having multiple actors that might issue arbitrary OpenGL commands at any time) as I have not seen a way to run any actor on a specific thread. Either by pinning a specific actor to a thread, or by instructing an actor to run on a specific thread at some point. (a la Objective-C's performSelectorOnMainThread)

Is there a way to pin a "rendering" actor to the main thread, or have any actor run on the main thread at some point in the future, at which point it will be able to issue OpenGL calls? (or even some other solution, I'm open to ideas)

Comment: Akka might not be a very good use case for this. While it does provide what you're asking for, it's only meant to be used for unit testing. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/testing.html#scala-callingthreaddispatcher

Comment: You may create a message loop in main thread and simply consume messages from actors. It may sit on some kind of a queue of `Runnable`'s.

Answer (score 2):

To pin execution thread of Akka actor you can use custom executor service configuration:

```
  akka {
    ...
    actor {
      ...
      my-dispatcher {
        executor = "com.github.plokhotnyuk.actors.CustomExecutorServiceConfigurator"
      }
    }
  }


class CustomExecutorServiceConfigurator(config: Config, prerequisites: DispatcherPrerequisites) extends ExecutorServiceConfigurator(config, prerequisites) {
  def createExecutorServiceFactory(id: String, threadFactory: ThreadFactory): ExecutorServiceFactory = new ExecutorServiceFactory {
    def createExecutorService: ExecutorService = myExecutorService()
  }
}
```

Full example is [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/AkkaUnboundedActorSpec.scala#L234)